# match or find value from sheet 1 and sheet 2

Tags: excel, vba

i have this code that checks if the value from h22 matches from entries in column i. how can i change the codes that it should check if h22 is an exact match with the last value on column i?

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Macro()

    Dim oWs As Worksheet
    Dim rSearchRng As Range
    Dim lEndNum As Long
    Dim vFindVar As Variant
    
    Set oWs = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    lEndNum = oWs.Range("I1").End(xlDown).Row
    Set rSearchRng = oWs.Range("I1:I" & CStr(lEndNum))
    Set vFindVar = rSearchRng.Find(Range("H22").Value)
    
    If Not vFindVar Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Match"
    Else
        MsgBox "No Match Found"
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Check Cell Against Last Cell in Column

- Checks if the value of the last non-empty cell in column `I` of worksheet `Sheet2` is equal to the value in cell `H22` of worksheet `Sheet1` and shows a message box.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CheckCellAgainstLastCell()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
 
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Dim slCell As Range: Set slCell = sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp)
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim dCell As Range: Set dCell = dws.Range("H22")
    
    If CStr(dCell.Value) = CStr(slCell.Value) Then
        MsgBox "It's a match.", vbInformation
    Else
        MsgBox "It's not a match.", vbCritical
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you so much. works as perfect as i want it to be.